# Haskell map on Right value of Either

Tags: haskell, monads, either

I have a type `Either a [b]` and a function `f :: (b -> c)`

How can I use `f` on a value of type `Either a [b]` to get `Either a [c]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fmap` function on it.

Either is an instance of the **Functor** typeclass with the first type fixed:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b

instance Functor (Either a)
  fmap _ (Left x)  = Left x
  famp f (Right y) = Right (f y)
```

and the fmap type for `Either a` therefore would be:

```
fmap :: (b -> c) -> Either a b -> Either a c
```

Appliction of fmap to Either leads to: **Left** data constructor of type a remains unchanged, and the **Right** data constructor of type b gets the function f applied to get to the type c.

Comment: But OP would have to write `fmap (fmap f) e` because their right type is `[b]`, correct?

Comment: Yes. And List is also an instance of the Functor typeclass (where fmap = map).

Comment: Thank you! It was this double `fmap` that I was missing